# Importing excel files selecting columnames based on row conditions

Tags: r, excel, import, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet that looks something like this: 
[image]

***I have two questions***:

First, I would like to import this into r using as column names the row where the **KEYWORD** observation is (row 6).
I know how to do this using conditioning on the row numbers

```
df<- read_excel("data.xlsx", skip = 5)
```

and this option yields what I want:

```
output<-structure(list(...1 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 2, NA, 6, NA), KEYWORD = c(NA,1299434, 1299434, 1299434, 1299434, 1299434, 1299434, 1299434,1299434), `colum Name...3` = c(NA, "safwea", "safwea", "safwea","safwea", "safwea", "safwea", "safwea", "safwea"), `colum Name...4` = c(NA, 2323, 2323, 2323, 2323, 2323, 2323, 2323, 2323), `colum Name...5` = c(NA,                                                      3434, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3434), `colum Name...6` = c(NA, 
2341, 2341, 2341, 2341, 2341, 2341, 2341, 2341)), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

output
```

However, I have to repeat this operation for multiple spreadsheets and they are not all identified by the row number but rather by the **KEYWORD** observation. Is there a way to import column names based on the value of a row (in my case **KEYWORD**)?

The **second question** adds another level of complication. While column names from B to F in the spreadsheet should be those in the line of the **KEYWORD**, the first column (A) should be named with the *name* in cell A1. 
I know how to rename the column individually, but I need to repeat the operation for multiple spreadsheets and I am looking for a concise way of doing it.

The final data in r should look like this:

```
output2<- structure(list(name = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 2, NA, 6, NA), KEYWORD = c(NA,1299434, 1299434, 1299434, 1299434, 1299434, 1299434, 1299434,1299434), `colum Name...3` = c(NA, "safwea", "safwea", "safwea","safwea", "safwea", "safwea", "safwea", "safwea"), `colum Name...4` = c(NA, 2323, 2323, 2323, 2323, 2323, 2323, 2323, 2323), `colum Name...5` = c(NA,                                                      3434, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3434, 3434), `colum Name...6` = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           2341, 2341, 2341, 2341, 2341, 2341, 2341, 2341)), row.names = c(NA,
```

Does anyone knows how to obtain this result in a coincise way?

Below I am posting the data structure of simply importing the data `df<- read_excel("data.xlsx")` so that it may help you in answering the question

```
df<-structure(list(Name = c(NA, "bla", "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla bla", 
NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, "2", NA, "6", NA), ...2 = c(NA, "bla", 
NA, "bla bla bla bla", "KEYWORD", NA, "1299434", "1299434", "1299434", 
"1299434", "1299434", "1299434", "1299434", "1299434"), ...3 = c(NA, 
"bla", "bla bla bla", NA, "colum Name", NA, "safwea", "safwea", 
"safwea", "safwea", "safwea", "safwea", "safwea", "safwea"), 
    ...4 = c(NA, NA, NA, "bla bla bla bla", "colum Name", NA, 
    "2323", "2323", "2323", "2323", "2323", "2323", "2323", "2323"
    ), ...5 = c(NA, "bla", NA, NA, "colum Name", NA, "3434", 
    "3434", "3434", "3434", "3434", "3434", "3434", "3434"), 
    ...6 = c(NA, NA, "bla bla bla", "bla bla bla bla", "colum Name", 
    NA, "2341", "2341", "2341", "2341", "2341", "2341", "2341", 
    "2341")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

this would be my workaround:

```
#read all lines without skip
df<- read_excel("data.xlsx")

#work out what row keyword is at
keyword_row_i <- min(which(df[,2]== "KEYWORD"))

#set that row as names
names(df) <- df[keyword_row_i,]

#for you second question, set first var's name to be cell A1
names(df)[1] <- df[1,1]

#then just drop rows above where data starts
df <- df[(keyword_row_i+1):nrow(df),]
```

Although doing that would likely set all columns to be characters so you'll need to convert as.int/numeric() etc..

Plus once you've got the keyword row number & the value of A1 from the first read you could just read in again with the "skip" parameter and then just update the name of column 1

Comment: yes I agree, sorry that's what I meant with my last sentence but re-reading it it wasn't very clear so thanks for clarifying

Comment: Martin, oops, I think I read that paragraph and then brain-dumped it ... and I think that that should be the primary mode, not an "aside": having the code read in all rows and manually convert each correct class is certainly not impossible (or even hard for basic cases), but `readxl` goes to great pains to try to do it smartly, efficiently, and consistently. And automatically. By not re-reading with `skip=`, the user is subverting that well-tested process. Anyway, this is the right approach.

Comment: when running the `keyword_row_i <- min(which(df[,2]== "KEYWORD"))` command I am getting the following warning when trying to apply it to the dataset: ````Warning message:
In min(which(df[, 2] == "KEYWORD")) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf````which is leading to problems with the following commands: do you know why this may be the case